# Parallel coordinates with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I need to to represent a Parallel Coordinates with d3.js. First of all I have no idea if what I think is possible to achieve (and if the Parallel Coordinates is the right chart). 
I will explain my idea: I take data from a database and I expose them in a JSON and I store them in an array of objects (with JavaScript). 
This is an example of the data http://pastebin.com/DZcMqDMc. 
I would like to represent along the abscissa axis years (though there are years repeating themself, as you can see from data example), while along the ordinate axis values of those years (values are in percent, ranging from 1 to 100). 
I would like to represent two lines according to "value1" and "value2" property in the JSON file.
Is it possible? Is Parallel Coordinates the right chart?

The main problem I have right now is that I do not understand how to set right the two domains (abscissa and ordinate).
I am basing on the example Parellel Coordinates of Bostock.

For abscissa I am thinking something like that:

```
x.domain(
    d3.extent(test, 
        function(d) {
            return d.years;
        }
    )
);
```

It makes sense or?

Comment: Yes, it's totally possible to create a parallel coordinates chart using d3. But what you're describing is, technically speaking, a line chart, not a parallel coordinates: "Parallel coordinate chart is closely related to time series visualization, except that it is applied to data where the axes do not correspond to points in time, and therefore do not have a natural order". In a true PC chart, you can change the order of the vertical axes the way you want.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado what you said was just what I was thinking. Thanks for point me in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try a  [multi line chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).That might suit your need.
I am not sure what you are trying.

Comment: Hi If anyone can help solve the issues with these parallel coordinates - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329600/d3-v4-parallel-coordinates-selection-of-paths-with-d3-v4-brushes     or    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334965/syntagmatic-nutrient-parallel-coordinate-chart-highlight-data-row  . It would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a line chart, and produce the vertical lines by formatting the ticks to go from 0 to height ( in your var xAxis code include .tickSize(0-height)). You will have to pick the right number of ticks, as in ticks(), so you just get the lines where you want them.

Comment: Hi If anyone can help solve the issues with these parallel coordinates - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329600/d3-v4-parallel-coordinates-selection-of-paths-with-d3-v4-brushes     or    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334965/syntagmatic-nutrient-parallel-coordinate-chart-highlight-data-row  . It would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Parcoords, a d3-based parallel coordinates library. For compatibility with d3 v5 see https://github.com/BigFatDog/parcoords-es which is based on the original Parcoords library (https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates) which relies on an outdated version of d3.

For examples and sample code, check out the following link: http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/.